# Angular material datepicker working without injecting dependencies

Tags: angularjs, datepicker, angular-material

Please find below the codepen which has the code for datepicker which has few scripts(moment.js, material.js) added but the dependencies are not injected in the app.

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/vNLyGJ

I checked the code by exporting, in which I can see the module is not created but called.

How does this works without injecting the dependencies in index.js.

```
angular.module('MyApp')
.controller('AppCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.myDate = new Date();

.config(function($mdDateLocaleProvider) {
 $mdDateLocaleProvider.formatDate = function(date) {
return moment(date).format('YYYY-MM-DD');
  };
 });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually the references are there, Click and you could see the references in the  **`Javascript`** tab,

[image]

[image]

**UPDATE:**

'ngMaterial' is being loaded as a dependency on another file at the end on that codepen:

```
https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/t-114/assets-cache.js

var demoExampleAppName = 'MyApp';
  angular.module(demoExampleAppName, ['ngMaterial', 'ngMessages'])
    .run(function($templateCache) {
      angular.forEach(assetMap, function(value, key) {
        $templateCache.put(key, value);
      });
});
```

MyApp Module is already defined in this case.

Comment: Kindly check in the js tab, while calling the angular app there is no dependency added.

Comment: got it thanks and how are they getting the moment inside the config without injecting or why is it not needed?

Comment: welcome! yes its also from cache. mark as anser if it has helped

Comment: It also from cache means. Can you be more specific?